# TYPO3 extension "news": Getting "Detail View" URL

Tags: typo3

I have started using the TYPO3 extension "news" and I would like to create in the LIST VIEW a "Facebook Like Button" for the Detail View of each enty. For this I need to fetch the URL of the DETAIL VIEW, not the whole `<a>` tag. How can i do this?

I tried this, but it didnt work:

```
<n:link configuration="{returnLast: 'url'}" newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}">
    Link to detail page
</n:link>
```

It uses Fluid Templates, which I'm completely new with, so I don't know how complicated this actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. parameter `uriOnly`:

```
<n:link uriOnly='1' newsItem='{newsItem}' settings='{settings}'></n:link>"
```

Comment: If you need the full url, you also need to append `configuration="{forceAbsoluteUrl: 1}"`