# TYPO3 extension news changes to the detail view

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-extensions

I've started using the news extension ([link](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/stable/singlehtml/Index.html)) and setup has gone well. I've changed the constants to use my own site-package as is told by the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/Start/Index.html). I've also included news in my static file list.

However when trying to change the detail view for my news pages (by creating a detail view inside my site_package) it doesn't seem to work. I am unable to add any changes. Also the url from news ends up being a very long string something like :

`/index.php?id=30&amp;tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=15&amp;tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&amp;tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&amp;cHash=c31900b3fb7edbad7fd46044e0ab3b02`

Searching through the documentation I cannot find any mention of this, nor am I able to find any questions related on Stackoverflow. I've tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290087/typo3-extension-news-getting-detail-view-url) but to no avail.

I'm not *that* well-versed with fluid templating so I'm not sure on the complications.

My TYPO3 Version is 8.7.18

Constants file in ext:news looks like the following

```
    view {
    # cat=plugin.tx_news/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (FE)
    templateRootPath = EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Templates/ext/news/Templates/
    # cat=plugin.tx_news/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (FE)
    partialRootPath = EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Templates/ext/news/Partials/
    # cat=plugin.tx_news/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (FE)
    layoutRootPath = EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Private/Templates/ext/news/Layouts/
}

settings {
    # cat=plugin.tx_news/file; type=string; label=Path to CSS file
    cssFile = EXT:my_site_package/Resources/Public/ext/news/news-basic.css
}
```

Comment: Did you add the news plugin with 'Detail' action on the detail page?

Comment: The link you posted looks okay: News UID 15 should be shown by class NewsController with method detailAction() at page UID 30.
I guess, your changes at the FLUID template e.g. EXT:yoursitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/News/Detail.html (or similar path) are not rendered in frontend? ClearCache? Check if path exists, as you typed for TypoScript constants plugin.tx_news.view.templateRootPaths.templateRootPaths.1
Maybe you post your TS code (constants) here.

Comment: If your TYPO3 version is < 9.5 and you want nice URLs instead of all the GET parameters, please have a look a the EXT:news documentation for EXT:realurl: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html

Comment: And like StatiX asked: do you expect to view details at page UID 30, where you have a news plugin, with correct settings for detail-view?

Comment: Sorry I should have noted my TYPO3 version. I'm currently running 8.7.18.

I've cleared the cache and my path exists. I can freely change the 'list' and 'item' templates without any issue. I've added my constants as well

Comment: My news plugin is currently added as a LIST view, I expect to view the details when I'm clicking on an item in the list view that i'll be getting a detail view with that item.

All my news items are currently stored within a folder called 'News-Overview' and I've set the starting point for the list view there.

Comment: It was indeed @StatiX suggestion I've added a detail page and set the pageID for single news to said page. The link works as needed. I'll have to check out the realURL doc. One last question; do I have to separate style the detail view so with another backend template or is there an easier way to do this? The detail.html template still seems to be ignored by my install